# How to get response of redux-saga action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga

I am trying to get response of `redux-saga` action which is returned from service. These are some snippets of my project.

```
// ACTION

const actions = {
  LOAD_CURRENT_ACCOUNT: 'user/LOAD_CURRENT_ACCOUNT'
};

export const currentUser = () => ({
  type: actions.LOAD_CURRENT_ACCOUNT
});
```

```
// SERVICE

export async function currentAccount() {
  try {
    const url = config.endpoints.user;
    const res = await http.get(url);

    return res.data;
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.response && err.response.data) {
      notification.warning({
        message: err.response.data.code,
        description: err.response.data.message
      });
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

```
// SAGA

export function* LOAD_CURRENT_ACCOUNT() {
  const res = yield call(currentAccount);

  if (res) {
    yield put({
      type: actions.SET_STATE,
      payload: res.data
    });
  }
}
```

Right now, when I try to log the response it simply returns action type object i.e. `"user/LOAD_CURRENT_ACCOUNT"` instead of this output I'm expecting API response.

```
// abc.js

const res = await store.dispatch(currentUser());

console.log(res);

// RESULT: "user/LOAD_CURRENT_ACCOUNT"
```

How can I get the API response here?

Comment: You can't, there could be multiple sagas listening for the same action. This is similar question to another I answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55664378/how-to-call-a-function-before-and-then-depending-on-data-update-state-react-redu

Comment: Do you have reducer for `actions.SET_STATE`? If you put response to the store, then you can easily subscribe your component to the api result